# Sandbox: Prompt to remove Game Center data when app is deleted?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios5, game-center

I've looked for an answer in the Apple Docs, and here and other sites, and cannot find anything. So I'm hoping to find someone who knows or has experience with it.

My app is using GameKit to store some Achievements (no scores or leaderboard). When I delete the app from the simulator, it is NOT prompting me if I want to delete the GameCenter data as well, like production apps usually do. Is this normal? Do I need to do anything specific to create this prompt? Or will it simply appear in the production version and is not available for some reason in the Sandbox?